# Submit MVC Form Results to HttpPost method and display model in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've seen lots of examples on how to use an ActionLink in a form to call a method on the controller.  When it hits that method it then returns a partial view within a bootstrap modal.  What I would like to do though is have my form post the form results to the HttpPost method on my controller and from there then call the partial view to display the bootstrap modal.  How can I do this?

Form View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ballotForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @(Html.EditorFor(m => m.BallotViewModel, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo
        {
            HtmlFieldPrefix = "BallotViewModel"
        }
    }))
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">Vote Management Ballot</button>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel bModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("ViewVoteConfirmation", bModel.BallotViewModel);
    }
}
```

_Layout:

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    // Initalize modal dialog
    // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
    // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        //$.post($(this).attr("href"), function (data) {
            // got the result in data variable. do whatever you want now
            //may be reload the page
        //});
    });

    // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
    });

    //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
    $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });

    $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what actually worked:**

I applied this code snippet to my layout page

```
$('#ballotForm').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var data = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr('target');

$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){

        $('#modal-container').modal('show');
        $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
        });

    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){ });
```

Initially it did not work.  So as @Tieson suggested, I moved

`$('#modal-container').modal('show');`

down below

```
$('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
 });
```

and that enabled the modal to fire.  So the altered working snippet looks like this:

```
$('#ballotForm').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var data = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr('target');

$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){

        $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
        });

        $('#modal-container').modal('show');

    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){ });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems relatively straight-forward.

1. Attach an eventhandler to the form's `onsubmit` event.
2. Cancel the normal event (you don't want the page itself to issue the POST request).
3. Serialize the form, so that you have some data to submit.
4. Grab the form's `target` property, so you know where to issue your POST.
5. Use jQuery's `$.post` function to issue an ajax request.
6. Your response is going to be a partial HTML page. We want to inject that into the body of the modal.

You should have something like this:

```
$('#ballotForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr('target');

    $.post(url, data)
        .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){

            $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
            });

            $('#modal-container').modal('show');

        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){ });

});
```

This assumes a sunny-day case. `.done()` handles all 2xx response codes, which doesn't necessarily mean your response is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Where do I specify the form target?  So if I add a breakpoint to my HttpPost method, when I submit the form will it hit the breakpoint first and then transfer the model to the view via the modal?

Comment: The target attribute is generated for you by the HtmlHelper. You can see this by inspecting the generated markup using something like Firebug or your browser's native developer console.

Comment: I added the snippet above and when I submit the form, the page grays out and it hits the HttpPost breakpoint which is correct up to this point.  When I let it run the rest of the way the modal never shows and the page stays in the grayed out state.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like it attempted to display the modal, but something erred in the `show.bs.modal` event. Do you see an error in the JavaScript console? Looking at what you have, you may need to change `.find('.modal-body')` to `.find('.modal-content')`.

Comment: Nothing shows in the console. I changed it modal-content but it still doesn't show the modal.

Comment: Add a `console.log(modal)` and a `console.log(response)`, which will let you verify that you have something to work with (and that the `show.bs.modal` event is being triggered).

Comment: would i put this before the $.post statement or within the .done function block?

Comment: Within the block that starts with `$('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal'`.

Comment: No difference.  I've updated my layout code above with your snippet and suggestions.  Please see if I have missed something.  I still any not having anything showing in the console.

Comment: It occurs to me that `$('#modal-container').modal('show');` might have to come after the `$('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal'` bit; otherwise, jQuery doesn't know to capture that event yet when `.modal('show')` is called.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks so much for all your help. I've updated the code snippets above.

Comment: Cool. I would update your question to either include your working version, leave the old version, or separate them (with something like "Here's what actually works" as a title between them). As it stands it's a little difficult to grok what the original question would have been. I did clean up the indents on your edit to the answer, though (you had two spaces, whereas everything else had four).

Comment: @JMO If working through the bugs helped you understand what you're trying to do, you can always post that as an answer - explain what you thought would work, and what wound up working, with some explanation of what you learned along the way. I'm sure it would help someone else.